# python: How to start and stop a logger whenever i want

Tags: python, django, python-logging

I am trying to log sql statements in a code in my Django Application

Currently i am using the following logger config in my settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'sql': {
            '()': SQLFormatter,
            'format': '[%(duration).3f] %(statement)s',
        },
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(funcName)s() %(pathname)s[:%(lineno)s] %(name)s \n%(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'sql': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'sql',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
}
```

In genereal to log sql in django we can add the `django.db.backends` to the logger.config in the settings.py

```
 'loggers': {
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['sql'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
    },
```

But the problem is it will log every sql statement. So how can we start and stop logging for `django.db.backends` in between code.

I have the following code in my views.py

```
def someview(request)
    # start logging from here
    user_set = User.objects.all()
    for user in user_set:
        print(user.last_name) 
    # stop logging from here
```

Also I want to use the `sql` handler which I defined in the logging config.

What code will go in start and stop logging place in the above view function.

Comment: Try with log level as INFO

Comment: You also can try`filters` in this scenario. Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/

Comment: can you show the code,

Comment: just change the log level to INFO and back to DEBUG whenever you want to start/stop

Comment: @TreantBG  i will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter class and add an instance to the logger or handler.

```
class LoggerGate:
    def __init__(self, state='open'):
        self.state = state

    def open(self):
        self.state = 'open'

    def close(self):
        self.state = 'closed'

    def filter(self, record):
        return self.state == 'open'
```

Create a filter, initialized  in the 'closed' state. 
Get the 'django.db.backends' logger and add the filter.

```
gate = LoggerGate('closed')
sql_logger = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
sql_logger.addFilter(gate)
```

Then call the `open` or `close` method to limit logging to where you want it.

```
def someview(request)
    gate.open()      # start logging from here

    user_set = User.objects.all()
    for user in user_set:
        print(user.last_name) 

    gate.close()     # stop logging here
```

Comment: How can add this class in the confi file and create its object where ever i want and then do open and close

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795153/python-logging-can-we-added-multiple-filters-to-the-logger-and-which-one-is-co (I have asked my above comment as a question based on your answer using filters. Can you have a look over it. So you can understand my need)

Answer (score 0):

Just summarizing from the above answer and also from the answer of [Gabriel C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795392/2897115), which both are same and also from the answer of [Sraw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795742/2897115)

My goal was to log sql using django [django.db.backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#django-db-backends). But the problem with it is that it will log all the sqls. I want to log only sqls in a particular section of a code or whereever i want to see the sqls. So the following way i could do it.

logging config inside settings.py:

```
# Filter class to stop or start logging for "django.db.backends"
class LoggerGate:
    def __init__(self, state='closed'):
        # We found that the settings.py runs twice and the filters are created twice. So we have to keep only one. So we delete all the previous filters before we create the new one
        import logging
        logger_database = logging.getLogger("django.db.backends")
        try:
            for filter in logger_database.filters:
                logger_database.removeFilter(filter)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        self.state = state

    def open(self):
        self.state = 'open'

    def close(self):
        self.state = 'closed'

    def filter(self, record):
        """
        Determine if the specified record is to be logged.

        Is the specified record to be logged? Returns 0/False for no, nonzero/True for
        yes. If deemed appropriate, the record may be modified in-place.
        """
        return self.state == 'open'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'sql': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'myfilter': {
            '()': LoggerGate,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['sql'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
            'filters': ['myfilter']
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the views.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger_database = logging.getLogger("django.db.backends")

def test1(request):


    logger_database.filters[0].open()
    #Will allow priting of sql satatements from here

    from django import db
    user_set = User.objects.all()

    for user in user_set: # Here sql is executed and is printed to console
        pass
    #Will stop priting of sql satatements after this
    logger_database.filters[0].close()

    from django import db
    user_set = User.objects.all()

    for user in user_set:  # Here sql is executed and is not printed to console
        pass

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>Internal purpose</body></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

If one wants to print the sql in formatted and colorful way use this in the settings.py

```
# SQL formatter to be used for the handler used in logging "django.db.backends"
class SQLFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):

        # Check if Pygments is available for coloring 
        try:
            import pygments
            from pygments.lexers import SqlLexer
            from pygments.formatters import TerminalTrueColorFormatter
        except ImportError:
            pygments = None

        # Check if sqlparse is available for indentation
        try:
            import sqlparse
        except ImportError:
            sqlparse = None

        # Remove leading and trailing whitespaces
        sql = record.sql.strip()

        if sqlparse:
            # Indent the SQL query
            sql = sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True)

        if pygments:
            # Highlight the SQL query
            sql = pygments.highlight(
                sql,
                SqlLexer(),
                #TerminalTrueColorFormatter(style='monokai')
                TerminalTrueColorFormatter()
            )

        # Set the record's statement to the formatted query
        record.statement = sql
        return super(SQLFormatter, self).format(record)




# Filter class to stop or start logging for "django.db.backends"
class LoggerGate:
    def __init__(self, state='closed'):
        # We found that the settings.py runs twice and the filters are created twice. So we have to keep only one. So we delete all the previous filters before we create the new one
        import logging
        logger_database = logging.getLogger("django.db.backends")
        try:
            for filter in logger_database.filters:
                logger_database.removeFilter(filter)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        self.state = state

    def open(self):
        self.state = 'open'

    def close(self):
        self.state = 'closed'

    def filter(self, record):
        """
        Determine if the specified record is to be logged.

        Is the specified record to be logged? Returns 0/False for no, nonzero/True for
        yes. If deemed appropriate, the record may be modified in-place.
        """
        return self.state == 'open'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'sql': {
            '()': SQLFormatter,
            'format': '[%(duration).3f] %(statement)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sql': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'sql',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'myfilter': {
            '()': LoggerGate,
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['sql'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
            'filters': ['myfilter']
        }
    }
}
```